# Can't access Google Run service with authenticated access

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run service on a GCP project with access point URL `https://reporting-intake-service-XXX-uc.a.run.app`.  And the service itself uses Pub/Sub to push a message.

**Update:** I have confirmed the issue is with the Pub/Sub invocation in the service and NOT the access to the service itself.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python3 intake.py
```

#### intake.py

```py
import logging
from flask import Flask, request
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def intake():
    try:
        report = request.data
        publish_message(report)
        return "Thanks"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return "ERROR"


def publish_message(report):
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    future = publisher.publish("projects/my-project/topics/reporting", report)
    logging.info(future.result())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080, host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

#### Error message:

```
status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED 
details = "User not authorized to perform this action."
```

#### What I've tried:

- Running a VM with service account permissions:

  - Cloud Run Invoker
  - Compute Instance Admin (v1)
  - Pub/Sub Admin

  The command to test:

  ```bash
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" -d "{'\id\': \'ThIS IS SOME DATA\'}" https://reporting-intake-service-XXX-uc.a.run.app
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  ERROR
  ```
- [Can't access google cloud run service from Firebase Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554898/cant-access-google-cloud-run-service-from-firebase-hosting)
- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token
- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#set-up-sa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it.

It turns out the Cloud Run service was made with the default Compute service account `###-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

`Cloud Run > click on service > REVISIONS > SECURITY`

The IAM principle attached to `###-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` was deleted (by me for security purposes).  So the underlying service I created on Cloud Run did not have access to PubSub.

I spent way too much time on this sh*t.

To be clear this is under the "Require authentication" schema.